# Data storage for stock price data, daily AND weekly?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design

I am storing price history data for 3500 different stocks from 1970 to present (with a cron job running to update it every day).

What is the best way to store this data? It will be used to run calculations based on both daily data and weekly data. Currently I am storing it as:

```
stock_id, date, closing_price, high, low, open, volume
```

Since I want weekly price as well, should I make a separate table to store:

```
stock_id, week_end_date, weekly_closing_price, weekly_high, weekly_low, week_open_price, average_daily_volume, total_weekly_volume
```

Since this data is all calculable from the first table, is it necessary to store it again? The only reason I am considering it is that there are a LOT of rows of data to be running calculations.....

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much data you have and if you what your other transactional requirements are.

It doesn't make sense to duplicate this data in your source/OLTP system if you have one.  I'm a SQL Server programmer, not MySQL, but I imagine they have datepart functions like all other RDBMS so determining a week number from a date is trivial.

When you get to OLAP or reporting, though, you may want to make another table with data at your week-level granularity.  This will make reporting much faster, especially for things like aggregations which typically don't perform well when run against the output of a function.

Both these depend on the scale of your data.  If you have hundreds of rows per day, it may not be worthwhile to do a materialized weekly table for that.  If you have tens of thousands of records per day then the performance benefits will probably make it a reasonable option.

Answer (score 0):

You ask if it's necessary?  Who knows. That depends on how much disk space you have.  However, what you are describing is an "old fashioned" aggregation table and is often used to improve reporting performance.  When dealing with historical data, there's no need to recalculate things like weekly totals since the data doesn't change.

In fact, if I were doing this, I'd also define "monthly" and "annual" summary tables for more flexibility, especially for so much history.  You can consider "standardizing" the data in such a way that each period is comparable.  Calendar months and weeks have different numbers of trading days so things like "average daily volume" might be misleading.

If you really want to get fancy, do some research on ROLAP solutions. It's a very broad topic but you might find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

> Since this data is all calculable from the first table, is it necessary to store it again?

It's not *necessary* to summarize it and store it. You can just create a view that does all the summary calculations, and query the view.

If you're going to run reports over the full range of data a lot, though, it makes sense to summarize it once, and store the result.  You're going to start with about 40 million rows. (3500 stocks * 43 years * about 265 days/year)

If I were in your shoes, I'd load the data, write the query for weekly prices, and test the performance. If it's too slow, insert the summary data into a table.